# When (if ever) the repeating AlarmManager's alarm is cancelled by the OS?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've written the app which uses the AlarmManager to schedule events. It is able to create `AlarmManager.setRepeating` and cancel `AlarmManager.cancel` repeating alarms. I'm wondering on what conditions these alarms may be canceled by the Android OS (not from my code). For example what will happen if I create the alarm and then uninstall my app? Shall the alarm be cancelled?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, yes installing the app will cancel your alarms ... also restarting your phone.
but for the second one you can refrish your alarms when device turn on.
*Regards*